# Apache server crash by high load

Tags: apache-httpd

My apache provides a nextcloud which is used by round about 1000 users. Once up to twice a week, the apache server crashes with the following log entry

```
[Mon Feb 12 09:20:09.909665 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1818046] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 138.201.111.59. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Mon Feb 12 09:20:10 2024 (1818046): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2)
```

By searching in the web I was told to set the privileges for my /tmp folder to 777. Unfortunately that didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: Also, that is strange advice. Was there any reasoning given?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There was just the hint to change the privileges of the /tmp folder

Comment: Yeah, that's called voodoo, not engineering. Ignoring his that can't explain what they recommended is generally a good rule of thumb!

Comment: Seems this link did the trick: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500005938262-Unable-to-restart-PHP-FPM-Apache-tmp-read-only-mode

Comment: If you have found the solution yourself, you may want to write it as as your own answer so that others facing a similar problem can benefit from your experience.